# Is there an API that detects the presence of .NET profiler?

Tags: .net, profiling, clr

I work on a mocking tool that uses Profiling API to rewrite IL instructions on the fly. Often our customers have more than one commercial product that use Profiling API and in many scenarios our profiler doesn't get loaded.

I would like to improve the customer experience by detecting the presence of .NET profiler. In case that a third party profiler is found I would like to print a message that will help the customers to configure their environment properly.

So far I haven't found a reliable way to detect the presence of .NET profiler. I thought about parsing the Windows Application Log messages with ID 1022 and trying to match by process id but it seems quite flaky. I checked that the SSCLI implementation and it turns out that there is a function **IsProfilerPresent()** that does the required check. Is there similar public Microsoft API that I can use?

Comment: All profilers use the same low-level profiler interface provided by the CLR.  So something like IsProfilerPresent() doesn't tell you anything about the specific profiler that's being used.

Comment: Yes, it's true. I was hoping to get the file name (.dll) that contains the profiler component. Then I guess I would examine it for interesting properties like "File description", "Product Name", etc. So, I guess I was hoping for GetProfilerModuleFileName(...) function. I will try with the Windows Application Log approach. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft provides an [Unmanaged Profiling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404386.aspx) API that enables a profiler to monitor a program's execution by the common language runtime (CLR). The API refer to two environment variables whether the process should connect to a profiler. These are

> - COR_ENABLE_PROFILING: The CLR connects to a profiler only if this environment variable exists and is set to 1.
> - COR_PROFILER: If the COR_ENABLE_PROFILING check passes, the CLR connects to the profiler that has this CLSID or ProgID, which must
>     have been stored previously in the registry. The COR_PROFILER
>     environment variable is defined as a string.

Taken from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384689.aspx)

I´m not an expert in profiling applications but the API seems to be the source you need.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Indeed, this is one of options. Unfortunately, more often the profilers clear the environment variables in order to prevent profiling child processes. Also, often the profilers use registry keys (HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework or HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework) to set up COR_* variables which also get cleared by the profilers once they are loaded (again to prevent profiling other processes). I was hoping that the CLR provides an API that I can use. Thanks.